# Query if Azure Cloud Service Staging slot is provisioned with VMs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cloud-services

I want to create an Azure Powershell Function that sends an alert if the staging slot of a Cloud Service is provisioned with VMs.

I tried using **Get-AzureDeployment** but it seems this doesn't work with .Net core and I can't seem to create a .Net Framework Function App.

I also tried **az resource list** but it doesn't seem to give me information on the status of the deployment

Answer (score 0):

It seems using Azure Powershell CLI from an Azure Function to do this is not straightforward. 
In the end, I made a REST request to management.azure.com which is simple and works.